# How to get android.Manifest.permission's value by a constants's name stored as a variable in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is what I want:

```
String x = "READ_PHONE_STATE";
Manifest.permission(x);
```

It should returns the same result as Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

I have tried:

```
Manifest.permission.class.getFields("READ_PHONE_STATE");
```

but there is this error

```
'getFields()' in 'java.lang.Class' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

[`getFields()` takes no parameter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class#getFields()) and returns a list of fields.

[`getField()` takes a `String` parameter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class#getField(java.lang.String)) and returns a `Field` whose name matches that parameter.

So, perhaps change `getFields()` to `getField()` in your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will try it out tomorrow

Comment: it thrown "Unhandled exception: java.lang.IllegalAccessException" error. Is that mean we can't do this to android.Manifest.permission?

Comment: @UWUgg: Sorry, but I have never tried using reflection on `Manifest.permission`.

Comment: It's fine. Thank you for the answer anyways :>